# Create a table from and SQL database containing a drop down menu with a list of names from another SQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to create a table with a drop down menu and submit button in each row. 
The drop down menu contains a list of advisers from an SQL table. When i  select and adviser and i press the submit button the id of the item in the current row along with then selected adviser id  or name must be sent to another page. In my case it is sent to delete.php.

My code bellow displays a drop down menu and a submit button for each row of the table, however when you press the submit button it will only work correctly if you press the submit button located at the bottom of the table, if i press any other it appears to not send the info from the drop down menu.

( i know my code appear messy, i am experimenting if something is unclear ask me and i will clarify.  ) 
 Thank you very much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    //this is he code for the qeue
// connect to the database udinh sqli
$con = get_sqli();
// get results from database

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
//select whole list of students from walk_in
mysqli_select_db($con,"login");
$sql="SELECT * FROM walk_in";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
mysqli_close($con);
//Table to dispaly qeueu of students
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th><th>Advisor Student wants to see</th><th>P ID</th><th>Select Advisor to notify on send</th><th>Send Student</th><th> </tr>";

echo "<tr>";

//create a table of students by displaying all the data from result and adding a button
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Advisor'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pid'] . "</td>";
   // echo '<form action="delete.php?id2=' . $row['id'] . '" method="post">';
    // drop down menu for selecting advisor as a form submission

    // used to name each submit button with the id from walk_in
    $formId =  $row['id'] ; 

 echo "<td>" ;
 //create a form to submit the sleected advisor and the seelcted student to be removed from the queue
 echo '<form action="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" method="post">';

 //another query used to retreive the list of advisors  to pupulate the drop down menu
 //create a drop down menu with advisors resulting from the queue
echo '<select name="formStatus">';
$con = get_sqli();
            mysqli_select_db($con,"login");
$sql="SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE level = 0 AND logged = 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!$result2) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

            //loops through all advisors for drop down menu creation
               while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                   $id = $row2['id'];
   echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
}
echo'<option selected="selected"></option>';

echo '</select>';
echo '<td><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value= "'.$formId.'" /><td>';
//echo '<td><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value=  /><td>';
//echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&advisor='. "lol" .'">Send</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";

}
// close table>
echo "</table>";


?>

<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the tables i am using:

[image]

login_details  table containing ADVISER  details

[image]

Comment: I don't see a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: don't spam tag if there's no relevant code for javascript/jquery.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Okay. You need to end the `</form>` after each submit-button. Second, why do you run the `SELECT` for the advisors for every line? Why not just run it once, and parse the array-result for each row? It seems there is no selection based on any criteria (it's just the same selection each row), so why run so many queries?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie  Thank you very much, that worked!   I will fix my query  implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to close the form, the issue has been fixed. Thank you all!